# variable columns with countif result in formula parse error

Tags: google-sheets

When I use this formula it gives me "formula parse error"

`=COUNTIF(sheet2!"&A1&"$1:"&B1&"$4, "*x*")`

on sheet1 the cell A1=C and B1=D
on sheet2 the range C1:D4 contains 2 times x.

in trying to make Google Sheets understand the code needs to be:
`=COUNTIF(sheet2!C$1:D$4, "*x*")` and result into number 2 because of 2 times x.

I want to change cells A1 and B1 on sheet 1 to lets say X and Y
and the code would update to:
`=COUNTIF(sheet2!X$1:Y$4, "*x*")`

but i only get formula parse errors...please help if possible, 
much love

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `indirect` for this:

```
=COUNTIF(indirect("sheet2!"&A1&"$1:"&B1&"$4"), "x")
```